# Mixed Boostrap grid size does not collapse at breakpoint

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am attempting to have a 6 column layout for desktop and larger. However, I would like to have the grid collapse into 4 for laptops. The collapse does not occur at the break point as expected with the code below. I tried changing it to class="container-fluid" to no avail. I can't seem to get it to act as expected.

```
<div class="row" id="content">
   <div class="col-lg-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-flex justify-content-center">

   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-flex justify-content-center">

   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-flex justify-content-center">

   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-flex justify-content-center">

   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
   </div>
</div>
```

Not sure if this is relevant, but the div is styled with the below using CSS

```
#content div{
    min-height: 350px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work. Just show me the complete code and i can see whats wrong

Comment: Yeah. Turns out it does work and I need sleep......Thank you!